# How to update the parent data when partial view data get updated?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am developing and ASP.NET MVC application.

I have the View which have a one partial view.

I do have quotation form and that form contains the Product list.
I have shown the product list using partial view.

as you can see in the picture, I do have a list of products , user can select product from list and its quantity and price and total will appear on that list itself.

now, my issue is I cant get the updated data in the parent view whenever user changes/adds Products, Quantity and Price.

Like in picture, though I have added many products, Text box in partial view showing correct figure  but  text box on parent view which I want to show the total figure again , showing old values....

How can I get done this thing ?

[image]

I have tried the below code in Jscript tag in View, but not working.... 
(txtGrandTotal is the textbox name of the partial view)

```
jQuery('#txtGrandTotal').on('input', function () {
    alert("Changed");
 })


    $('#txtGrandTotal').change(function () {
        alert("Changed");
    });


    $('#txtGrandTotal').bind('input', function () {
        alert("Changed");
    });
```

Comment: You should use client-side logic, JavaScript for example.

Comment: It will be nice if you explain in brief, I have tried Change,Bind,input events of jquery but not working....

Comment: If you already tried that, please post the code. It would be easier.

Comment: Is `txtGrandTotal` the input in your parent or partial view?

Comment: It's probably just a problem related to the moment you're binding the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the the total input in your partial view has the id `txtGrandTotal` and the one in the parent view has the id `txtParentGrandTotal` you can use the following:

```
$('#txtGrandTotal').change(function() {
     $('#txtParentGrandTotal').val($(this).val());
});
```

Please note that your need to execute this code on `document ready` in the partial view, so that the jQuery `select` (`$('#txtGrandTotal')`) correctly returns your target element.